# How to make opacity of view with transparent, infliction, subtraction

Tags: android, xml, opacity, transparent, alpha-transparency

How to make background opacity of the View (for ex. EditField )with transparent, infliction, subtraction "Screen" like it is in Photoshop?

I know if I set background to `"@android:color/transparent"` for EditField then white background will be visible, but not main backgrounf of the layout

I need to implement this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it simply.. not by any code.. the only way  to do that is to get a drawable .png image(you need photoshop to create it) that has this shape(semi tranaparent on the frame ans fully transparent inthe center with rounded corners)..  make it with small width .. and use 9patch tool for stretching (so you can get flexible width)...

Comment: Okay you can do it by code... There is a way but it's very complicated.. use transparent back ground for edittext.. and surround it with semi-transparent views...you will need at least 8 views.. I don't like it.. it's a fail